# Cloudfront Gzip compression not working with files on site

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have enabled gzip page compression via Cloudfront on my behaviors. I have whitelisted the following headers:

```
Authorization
Host
Origin
Referer
```

The file in question is not being gzipped by Cloudfront. Here are the Request and Response Headers.

Why is the gzip not working? The headers have gzip and content-length values so that's the requirement from cloudfront as far as I understand.

```
Request Header

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate, sdch

Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8

Cookie  SESSef4017ccd367c98fbaadc=56e41ddb0fc0e0235cf8c5f7f18;
_ga=GA1.2.1714162874.1474376389;

has_js=1

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1

User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36


Response Header

Accept-Ranges   bytes

Age 25

Cache-Control   max-age=172800

Content-Length  614

Content-Type    text/css

Date    Wed, 21 Sep 2016 16:04:28 GMT

Expires Fri, 23 Sep 2016 16:04:28 GMT

Last-Modified   Wed, 16 Jan 2013 21:09:10 GMT

Server  Apache

Via 1.1 xxxx.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)

X-Amz-Cf-Id xxxxxxxxxxZ3lir8aOV5mykyezionEw==

X-Cache Hit from cloudfront
```

Comment: I also invalidated the file in cloudfront but still not gzipping

Comment: Anyone want to help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi the file size above which cloudfront will gzip is 1000 bytes. so a few of my .css files were below that hence gzip wasn't happening. Gzip via cloudfront works now.